dbt - databricks : support for dynamic replace where conditions
I am trying to implement an incremental model with a replace where condition using dbt on (Azure) Databricks.
My objective: I have order collection dataset I am building in my warehouse which I am building with incremental replace where strategy. I query the source as SELECT * FROM SOURCE WHERE SOURCE_DT >= (SELECT (MAX(dt) - 7) FROM warehouse table) and then I want to replace where this in my warehouse table.
{% set lookback_subquery %}
  SELECT dateadd((
          SELECT MAX(order_dt) from warehouse_table
      ), -7)
{% endset %}
{% set cutoff = run_query(lookback_subquery) %}
{% if execute %}
    {% set cutoff_val = cutoff.columns[0].values()[0] %}
    {{ log("ordercutoff " ~ cutoff.columns[0].values()[0], info=TRUE) }}
{% endif %}

{% set lookback_predicate %}
    order_date >= {{ cutoff_val }}
{% endset %}

{{
    config(
      materialized='incremental',
      incremental_strategy='replace_where',
      incremental_predicates=[lookback_predicate]
    )
    
}}

WITH TAB AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM
    SOURCE src
    WHERE
    {% if is_incremental() %}
      src.order_dt>= DATE_ADD((SELECT order_dt FROM {{ this }}), -7)
    {% else %}
      src.order_dt >= DATE_ADD(current_date(), -365)
    {% endif %}
)
SELECT * FROM TAB

I got the inspiration for this from this GitHub issue raised - here but this does not seem to work for databricks/delta table. Basically, the sql statement is just not rendered correctly. It just actually parses as {{ cutoff_val }}. I have also tried this, but in this scenario, the lookback_subquery does not render at all.
{% set lookback_predicate %}
    order_date >= {{ lookback_subquery }}
{% endset %}

{{
    config(
      materialized='incremental',
      incremental_strategy='replace_where',
      incremental_predicates=[lookback_predicate]
    )
    
}}

The main reason is, databricks/delta requires that replacewhere query be completely rendered. It cannot accept a subquery to specify the replacewhere parameters.
For example,
this works -
INSERT INTO MAIN_TABLE
REPLACE WHERE dt >= "2024-03-20"
TABLE TAB2_WITH_NEW_AND_SMALL_OVERLAP_W_MAIN_DATA 

but this does not work (basically if I add a subquery, the replace where does not work, it fails with table not found error)
INSERT INTO MAIN_TABLE
REPLACE WHERE dt >= (SELECT DATEADD((SELECT MAX(dt) FROM MAIN_TABLE), -7)
TABLE TAB2_WITH_NEW_AND_SMALL_OVERLAP_W_MAIN_DATA 

The actual queries are quiet large, so I have added sudo code here. But the main issue I am trying to address is -

how can I run get the actual date and pass it to the incremental_predicates (not as a subquery but like a rendered value). Can I run an macro inside a model and pass the value to the predicate?

Any thoughts on how to workaround this? Seems like a fairly common use case to use replacewhere on last X days of data.. not sure what I am missing here.
Thank you!
